# How do I keep the hover state of a div even after I clicked it?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a Nav menu and I want the list item's hover state to still be 'hovered' even after I clicked it and even if it hides. I want it to stay hovered no matter what until I click another list item. How do I do this?

Here's the JSFidde link https://jsfiddle.net/dpcrpfj5/26/
ALSO jQuery isnt working in this JSFiddle link I dont know know why..

Thank you for your time

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
$("#menutoggle").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("hov");
});


$('#menutoggle').click(function(){
    $('#mobilemenu').toggle('blind');
});


$("#mobilemenu li").one("mouseover", function() {
    $("#mobilemenu li").toggleClass('hover');
});
```

})

Comment: `$(document).on('ready', handler);` is bad syntax, doesn't use ready promise internally. So because you wrap your code inside `onload` handler in jsFiddle, this is too late for the ready pseudo event to be fired. Use relevant syntax instead, e.g: `$(document).ready(handler);`

Comment: hey thanks ! ill keep this in mind next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a 'hover' class to the clicked element, remove it from every other list-item and style it:

```
$(function() {
    $("#menutoggle").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("hov");
    });


    $('#menutoggle').click(function(){
        $('#mobilemenu').toggle('blind');
    });


    $("#mobilemenu li").click(function() {
        $("#mobilemenu li").removeClass('hover');
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#mobilemenu li:hover,
#mobilemenu li.hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -4px 0px 0px 0px #f1163c;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -4px 0px 0px 0px #f1163c;
    box-shadow: inset -4px 0px 0px 0px #f1163c;
    background: #17181c;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dpcrpfj5/28/